# Google actions fails to read error response and end the session smoothly

Tags: actions-on-google

I have an actions project built and working. I'm trying to handle some error scenarios where it is failing. I need some help there.
I have a scenario where the webhook call throws a proper JSON formatted error response as shown below but which couldn't not be read at google end. Not sure if that is google actions limitation. Because of this issue I couldn't trigger a webhook handler back to my server to end the open conversation smoothly.

```
{
 “responseJson”: {
“error”: {
  “message”: “Transaction cancelled: maximum execution time exceeded”,
  “detail”: “Transaction cancelled: ****”
},
“status”: “failure”
}
}
```

In the Error & status handling of actions scenes I dont see any system intent other than Cancel to handle any such error scenarios, I don't see any other relevant system intents too.
In simple words, I'm trying to catch a bad response and trigger back a webhook call to end the conversation at server side.
Could someone suggest a way to deal with this issue?

Comment: FYI, Unfortunately I cannot change the error response format at this point of time.

Comment: Where is your webhook being hosted? Is there some issue on the hosting end?

Comment: @NickFelker webhook is hosted in my secure employer instance. I dont think there is any issue at the hosting end. There is a transaction timeout at hosting end when occurs the thread gets killed and the above exception is thrown.

Comment: Your issue is that your webhook will sometimes fail and you need to find a way to catch that gracefully in your Actions Builder model?

Comment: @NickFelker yes you are right.

Comment: Can you create an intermediary webhook that calls from within your instance that can catch the transaction error and adjust the response accordingly?